# Inserting data into SQL database using EF

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I'm trying to create HttpPost method to create a new database entry. It should take 2 foreign IDs from different database tables and "name". Here's the model:

```
public class Domena
{
   public int DomenaID { get; set; }  // this domains ID
   public int TLDID { get; set; }     // foreign id
   public int KlientID { get; set; }  // foreign id
   public string Nazwa { get; set; }
   public virtual TLD TLD { get; set; }
   public virtual Klient Klient { get; set; }
}
```

Right, so basically this is what I have now :

```
// GET: /Domena/Add_Domain
public ActionResult Add_Domain()
{
   ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
   ViewBag.KlientID = new SelectList(db.Klienci, "KlientID", "KlientID");
   return View();
}

//
// POST: /Domena/Add_Domain

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add_Domain(Domena domena)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      db.Domeny.Add(domena);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ", domena.TLDID);
   ViewBag.KlientID = new SelectList(db.Klienci, "KlientID", "KlientID", domena.KlientID);
   return View(domena);
}
```

The way it works now is, it will display a drop-down list from which I can choose TLDID by "Typ" and KlientID by "KlientID" entry in the database. Also it ask for a "Nazwa", which is name that has to be written.

I want to remove the option to choose the KlientID from the dropdownlist and instead make HttpPost take the KlientID from the link. Example :

1. I go to client's details page : `/Klient/Details/6`
2. I click on Add_Domain link which takes currently viewed KlientID and takes me to: `/Domena/Add_Domain/6`

So, my question is, how can I modify both Get and Post methods in order to create a new "domena" entry in the database to the client's id which is in the link ?

Do I have to change anything in view as well ?

Here is my current Add_Domain view fieldset :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Domena</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TLDID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("TLDID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TLDID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KlientID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("KlientID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KlientID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nazwa)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nazwa)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nazwa)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default MVC routes `{controller}/{action}/{id}` you should able to leverage the `id` parameter. The `Add_Domain` link in your client page would set a route value:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a domain", "Add_Domain", "Domena",
    new { id = Model.KlientID }, null)
```

You give the GET action a parameter and set this parameter on the model:

```
public ActionResult Add_Domain(int id)
{
    ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
    var model = new Domena { KlientID = id };
    return View(model);
}
```

And in your view you remove label and validation message for `KlientID` and replace the drop down list by a hidden input:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.KlientID)
```

In the POST action you only remove the `ViewBag.KlientID = ...` line. The rest can remain unchanged. The MVC model binder will bind the hidden field to the `domena.KlientID` property.

The `id` parameter is a bit misused here because this `id` usually is related to the model the `Domena` controller is dealing with, so usually a `DomenaID` and not a `KlientID`. But it should still work. I would consider to use a query parameter instead to make it clearer that the last parameter in the route is a `KlientID`:

The action link would be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a domain", "Add_Domain", "Domena",
    new { klientID = Model.KlientID }, null)
```

And the GET action is:

```
public ActionResult Add_Domain(int klientID)
{
    ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
    var model = new Domena { KlientID = klientID };
    return View(model);
}
```

POST action is the same. The created link is then `/Domena/Add_Domain?klientID=6`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I've also replaced the "return RedirectToAction(Index)" with this "return RedirectToAction("Details", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Klient", Id = klientID }));" and it works very nice and takes me back to clients details page.